# How to copy certain rows to a different range on a different sheet using VBA in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, copy

The general idea of what I'm trying to do is copy certain rows from one sheet that meet a certain criteria (which I will explain in the next sentence), and then paste those rows in a different range on a newly created sheet in the same workbook. The criteria to grab a certain row is if the value in the first cell of that row is within a range specified by the user. For example, if the user enters in '4' for the lower bound and '8' for the upper bound, my code would only grab rows where the value in the first cell (in column A) is 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8 (it would grab those 5 rows).

There are 5 main steps to what I'm trying to do:

1. Create a new sheet in the workbook (lets call it QuoteCSV)
2. Have the user enter in information through a UserForm
3. Take that data from the UserForm and fill it in a certain number of rows on new QuoteCSV sheet
4. Copy certain rows from sheet1 based on criteria described above
5. Paste those rows on the same lines as the user-entered data rows that I filled in in step 2

So far, I'm able to do steps 1-4. I am getting an error when trying to do step 5. Here is my code

```
Sub exportDataToCSVSheet()
    
    'STEP 1 - create new sheet
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "QuoteCSV"
    
   'set header names on first row of new sheet
    Dim setValue_Var As Range
    Set setValue_Var = Sheets("QuoteCSV").Range("A1:V1")
    setValue_Var.Value = Array("H.SalesOrderNo", "H.ARDivNum", "H.CustomerNum", "H.CustomerPONum", "H.OrderDate", "H.ShipToName", "H.ShipToAddress1", "H.ShipToAddress2", "H.ShipToCity", "H.ShipToState", "H.ShipToZipCode", "H.ShipVia", "L.ItemCode", "L.ItemType", "L.CommentText", "L.DropShip", "L.QuantityOrdered", "L.UnitPrice", "L.UnitCost", "L.SerialNumber", "L.RenewalStartDate", "L.RenewalEndDate")
    
    
    Sheets(1).Select 
    'this gets you back to the first sheet of the workbook which 
    'is where I will be grabbing rows for step 4
    

    'ask user for input line values, these are the lower and upper bounds I talked about earlier
    FirstL = Application.InputBox("First line item num", "Please enter num", , , , , , 1)
    LastL = Application.InputBox("Last line item num", "Please enter num", , , , , , 1)

    'LineCount will be how many rows of data I am grabbing from Sheet1 as well as how 
    'many rows I will populate with the userform data 
    LineCount = (LastL - FirstL) + 1
    
   

    'STEP 2 - here is where I get user data for header items
    Dim frm As New UserForm1

    ' Show as modal - code waits here until UserForm is closed
    frm.Show vbModal
    
    'grabbing values from userform
    fson = frm.son
    fdiv = frm.divnum
    fcnum = frm.custnum
    fcponum = frm.custponum
    Dim frdate As String
    frdate = frm.monthCB + "/" + frm.dayCB + "/" + frm.yearCB
    cname = frm.shipname
    add1 = frm.add1
    add2 = frm.add2
    city = frm.city
    state = frm.state
    zip = frm.zip
    shipvia = frm.shipcomp
    
    'STEP 3 - pasting the userform data onto the specified number of rows starting from A2 and down
     With Sheets("QuoteCSV")

        Sheets("QuoteCSV").Select

        ' Get the current row
        Dim curRow As Long
        If .Range("B1") = "" Then
            curRow = 1
        Else
            curRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If

        'Add items to the first row (row 2)
        .Cells(curRow, 1) = fson
        .Cells(curRow, 2) = fdiv
        .Cells(curRow, 3) = fcnum
        .Cells(curRow, 4) = fcponum
        .Cells(curRow, 5) = frdate
        .Cells(curRow, 6) = cname
        .Cells(curRow, 7) = add1
        .Cells(curRow, 8) = add2
        .Cells(curRow, 9) = city
        .Cells(curRow, 10) = state
        .Cells(curRow, 11) = zip
        .Cells(curRow, 12) = shipvia

        'This copies the new row I just made down for however many rows of data we will be grabbing in step 4
        With .Range("A2:L2")
            .Resize(LineCount).Value = .Value
        End With

    End With
    
    
    'Make sure original sheet with data we want to grab next is now active sheet
    Sheets(1).Select
    
    
    ' Close the form
    Unload frm
    Set frm = Nothing
    
    
 
    'STEP 4 - code to grab rows that fit the criteria and move to new workbook

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    'filter for rows where the value in the first cell is within the correct range
    With wb1.ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & FirstL, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Field:=1, Criteria2:="<=" & LastL
    End With


    Set sht2 = Sheets("QuoteCSV")

    'STEP 5 - I am trying to copy the rows and paste them on the same lines as the userform data
    'but i get an error which I will describe and show below
    With wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .EntireRow.Copy sht2.Range("M2")
    End With
   
    wb1.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    
End Sub
```

Here is what the new QuoteCSV sheet will look like after Step 3
[image]

I know I am doing Step 4 right because if I comment out the block of code for step 3, enter in 8 and 11 as my upper and lower bounds, and then change the range from "M2" to "A2" in this section of code,:

```
With wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .EntireRow.Copy sht2.Range("A2")
End With
```

the correct rows are pasted in as shown here (disregard the blank row 2):

[image]

What I want to do, and what my code is trying to do is put that data on the lines next to the userform data. Ultimately after running my code, I want the new sheet to look like this:

[image]

However, when I try to run my code above as it is, I get an error when I get to this line at the end

```
'STEP 5 - I am trying to copy the rows and paste them on the same lines as the userform data
    'but i get an error which I will describe and show below
    With wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .EntireRow.Copy sht2.Range("M2")
    End With
```

Here is the error:

[image]

One thing I want to mention is that I only have about 33 header names in the first row of the new sheet at the moment but I know I will need to add more because the data goes past 33 cells. I tried adding more header cells to see if that fixed it but it still gave me the same error.

Obviously the data I am grabbing from the original sheet is more complex (has formatting and formulas going on in some cells) than the userform data that I paste in in step 3. I'm not sure if I'm getting that error because of this or if it's something else, but I would love some help to try and figure this out. Thank you

Comment: You can't copy an entire row into `M2`, or into any other column than A. You can't "fit" an *entire* row if you start in column M. Sounds like you need to find the last column in your source data.

Comment: Aren't I trying to paste the rows starting at the Range of M2? Meaning I am trying to paste the rows so that the upper left value of the first row will go in M2.

If not, how can I make it so it will paste the rows starting in cell M2 (so it is next to the userform data)?

Comment: An entire row is literally the *entire* row, every single cell in a row. If you try to paste an entire row in any other column than column A, you'll get an error. You only want to copy the cells with data.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get what you are saying. The last column of actual data that I need from the original sheet is column Q. Am I able to specify that when I am copying the rows in step 4?

Comment: Yes, `wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Q" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Copy sht2.Range("M2")`.

Comment: If you press [Ctrl]+[End] and not landed on some far away blank cells: try Intersect that .EntireRow with UsedRange before copy to sht2.Range("M2"). e.g. `Set oRngCopy = Intersect(.EntireRow, .Worksheet.UsedRange) : oRngCopy.Copy sht2.Range("M2")`

Comment: @BigBen I tried making that exact change right before you replied and I still am getting the same error as shown above saying that the copy and paste area aren't the same size. are there any other changes I need to make? I'm trying to look and think about it now

Comment: @PatricK I'm sorry, I literally have only been coding in VBA for 2 days total now so all of this is pretty new to me. I'm confused by what you are saying, is that line of code you put meant to replace this line of code of mine: `wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Q" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)         .Copy sht2.Range("M2")` ?

Comment: @BigBen Nevermind I got it, your change to my code worked, thank you so much! Like I said in another comment, I am literally brand new to VBA, had never used or seen it before a few days ago

Comment: @BigBen Last thing, do you happen to know which line of code is adding that blank first row in the second picture on my post? I found out that that blank line is the very first line in the original sheet that I copy the data from. I can't seem to make it so it doesn't copy over that additional line

Comment: Yes, my 2 lines to replace your `.EntireRow.Copy sht2.Range("M2")` in that Step 5 With block. Define *oRngCopy* as `Dim oRngCopy As Range`